# spinner con pagina emergente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Necesito por medio de un formulario al enviarlo se muestre un spinner con fondo negro que no le permita al usuario hacer alguna función o dar click en alguna parte de la pagina.

mi spinner funciona, al enviar un formulario, pero no se muestra como una pagina modal.

**html**

```
<div class="loader">
                        <img src="Spinner-1s-200px.gif" />
                    </div>
```

**css**

```
.loader {
  display: none;
}

.loader.active {
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
<script>

        $("#formulario").submit(function(e){
            $(".loader").addClass("active");
        });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El css está incompleto para volverlo un modal... tienes que darle un tamaño, una posición e idealmente un z-index y background para que aparezca como modal...

```js
const button =document.querySelector('button');
const spinner = document.querySelector('.loader');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  spinner.classList.add('active');
});

spinner.addEventListener('click', function() {
  spinner.classList.remove('active');
})
```

```css
.loader {
  display: none;
  position:fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.loader.active {

  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
                        <img src="https://c.tenor.com/I6kN-6X7nhAAAAAj/loading-buffering.gif" />
                    </div>
                    
 <button>
    click me
 </button>
```